# How to create compile-time class fields using templates?

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, c++17, template-meta-programming

## Little background and rationale

I am designing a compile-time ECS. The design has its specifics - for instance, there will be a great variety of entities. This means that the overall number of components is likely to be fairly high whilst number of components per entity will be fairly low (having some obvious present-almost-everywhere-commons such as `Sprite` or `BoundingBox`)

## My approach

I would implement the following interface:

```
/* Tell the compiler which fields we would use in this entity */
Entity<GraphicsComponent, PhysicsComponent> entity;

/* Populate the handles with the appropriate data (integer, pointer, doesn't matter) */
// via explicit creation
Entity.add<GraphicsComponent>(RenderSystem::create<GraphicsComponent>());
// or in some other way?
```

The inception of the `Entity` class I wrote:

```
template <typename ...>
class Entity final {};
```

I have, however, no idea how would I **create the handle data fields for the respective Component types**, and if it is even possible at all. Can anyone help me or explain why it wouldn't work (or possibly suggest a different solution)?

Comment: `std::vector<std::variant>` is an obvious solution, but I doubt it bodes well for your memory footprint

Comment: Actually, I don't really understand your question. What is it you want to do but cannot?

Comment: @PasserBy I am trying to add class fields to a class of types specified in `<>` (in the case above `GraphicsComponent` and `PhysicsComponent`). These would be handles I'd populate later via the `add` method as shown above (or, alternatively, as I am thinking about it now, in the constructor, like this: `Entity<GraphicsComponent, PhysicsComponent> entity(graphics, physics);`)

Comment: I don't actually need to create the class fields, just satisfy the interface shown above, however, I am unaware how it could be done without class fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `std::tuple`. N.b. the `get` requires that each of `Components...` is a distinct type

```
template <typename ... Components>
class Entity final { 
    std::tuple<Components...> components;  
    template<typename Component>
    void add(Component component) // possibly cv / ref qualified
    {
        std::get<std::decay_t<Component>>(components) = component;
    }
};
```

Comment: Yes, `std::tuple` is the way to go! Thank you, it works like charm! :)

Answer (score 2):

Use `std::variant` for a mixture of flexibility and simplicity, at the cost of possibly sacrificing some memory.

```
template<typename... Components>
class Entity final {
    using variant = std::variant<Components...>;
    std::vector<variant> components;

public:
    template<typename T>
    void add(T&& t) {
        components.push_back(std::forward<T>(t));
    }
};
```

The memory problem arises when your component have largely varying sizes. Say one is 1 byte while another is 200 bytes, all the entries in the `std::vector` will be at least 200 bytes large.

Another solution is `std::any`.

```
template<typename... Components>
class Entity final {
    std::vector<std::any> components;

public:
    template<typename T>
    void add(T&& t) {
        static_assert((std::is_same_v<Components, std::decay_t<T>> || ...));
        components.push_back(std::forward<T>(t));
    }
};
```

`std::any` most certainly have everything on the heap except very small objects, but doesn't suffer from the aforementioned problem with `std::variant`.

In the case with `std::any`, we use the type system only to enable checks, not to govern the layout of data.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I learnt something new today again! :D However, looking at Caleth's answer, doesn't `std::tuple` sort of circumvent this problem altogether?

Comment: @sjaustirni I refrain from suggesting `std::tuple` because it defeats a large portion of the purpose of having an ECS. `std::tuple` takes the type system to the extreme and ensures everything is static, but an ECS often does __not__ want that.

Comment: Doesn't the usage of templates ensure that everything is resolved in compile time anyway? As I mentioned, I am not going to use scripting, I want the ECS to be compile-time-only. What advantages could be possibly brought to the table by using `vector` over `tuple`?

Comment: @sjaustirni Being compile-time-only _is_ the limitation. For example, if you wanted an entity that, otherwise identical, will be changing between being controlled by players and AI. Being completely static means you would either have different types representing the source of control, or you would have to have a source of control that can handle both player input and AI controls. The former is a nightmare with a completely static `Entity`, the latter is simply postponing the problem.

Comment: @sjaustirni I'm not saying you will be using that, but that is what we call _flexibility_.

Comment: I was just asking out of curiosity. Thank you kindly for your responses! You're an amazing teacher :)